# How to copy & paste table with merged cells from excel to a web page?

Tags: javascript, html, excel, csv, copy-paste

When pasting into a **textarea** a table copied from **excel**, it converts to a CSV, separated by \t for cells, and \n for rows.
But when coping a merged cell, it places the value only into the first cell.
Is there a way to get more information about the table structure than just the plain CSV?

for example, table like:

```
| dispersion |   center     |   |
| min  | max | avg | median | N |
```

becomes:

```
| dispersion |     | center |        |   |
| min        | max | avg    | median | N |
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a possible solution:
Using a `<div contenteditable="true"></div>` instead of a `textarea`.
When coping a table to the editable div, it pastes an HTML, with colspan when needed, instead of a CSV.